# MySQL find duplicate products and update column

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am working on a website using opencart and have it setup to automatically import products from two different wholesalers. The database contains about 40,000 different products in it, and about 10,000 of them are duplicates (both carry the product).

I need to lookup all duplicate products (by UPC) and enable the product with the lower price.

The table is called "product" and has the columns product_id, upc, price, status, and others that aren't relavent.

My first attempt was to run the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
upc
) AS upcDuplicate, COUNT( upc ) AS upcCount
FROM product
GROUP BY upc
HAVING upcCount >1
```

which gave me a list of all duplicate products, then I was going to loop through those upcs in php and run

```
UPDATE product SET status=1 WHERE upc='CURRENTUPC' ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1
```

which would enable the one with the lowest price.

This works, but seems very inneficient seems how it is relying on php to run 10,000 different mysql queries. Is there any way to put this into a single query, or at least something more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, so it may kick your dog and steal your lunch money, but...

```
UPDATE product
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT upc, MIN(price) AS minprice
    FROM product
    GROUP BY upc
) AS derived_product
SET product.status=1
WHERE product.upc = derived_product.upc AND product.price=derived_product.minprice
```

Comment: Appears to have worked great. I will go through and check some of the data, but what you wrote makes perfect sense. I didn't even think about using MIN() in the query.

The also allows me to activate all of the products that don't have duplicates in the same shot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this in PHP, you can always create a procedure at the DB level and call it from your PHP code, which will at least save the conversation time (9999 in this case) between PHP and DB